# how does vhdl guarantee timing constraints

Tags: vhdl, counter, flip-flop

my question is, imagine you have counter, having output connected to register. Now on falling/rising edge of clock register (FF) stores data and counter generates new data, but what if counter is really fast and data arrives at register's input in time less then hold time? it won't store previous value correctly, right? how does vhdl handle such situations?

Answer (score 1):

The language doesn't guarantee anything. The synthesis tool, along with the place and route tool figure this out by knowing the min/max and uncertainties of all the interconnections for a given device and its expected PVT (process, voltage, temperature) parameters. These parameters come from the vendor and are baked into the design tools.

The process is roughly this: synthesis figures out which "blocks" (CLBs/ALMs, hard cores like RAM, DSP and PLL, etc.) are needed to satisfy your design and determines how to connect them, generating a netlist. This netlist then gets sent to the P&R tool which tries to fit everything into the specified device. During this P&R task the known delays between block A and block B are taken into account and summed (this is a simplification). Out of this you get a timing report, which is essentially a giant list of every connection and the best- and worst-case time for a signal to get from one to the next. Your maximum frequency (how fast you can run the design) comes out of this and is based on the placement and netlist that has been provided.

Your constraints file is the bit where you define the required timing in the design. Perhaps you have a source-synchronous interface to an external PHY or you have some other bus which has specific setup and hold times between the clock, control and data signals. Constraints can also come from the interactions between internal blocks within the device. This constraints file is used during place and route to help guide placement and routing, but also in the final timing check to make sure that all of the setup and hold times you have specified have been met in the design, given an operating temperature, core voltage and specific target device.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all.
VHDL describes the general behaviour but not the timing. Timing simulation can be done after synthesis, but at that time, the Synthesizer already should have taken timing constraints into account.

Comment: so if hold time is violated how is synthesizer gonna fix it?